# how to prevent multiple decimals in javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, function, return-value, calculator, document

I am making a javascript calculator and have problem with decimals.I need them to output only once.I will show an example with dots (I need 0.55 and code can make 0....5).This code outputs "." right after some number was clicked,after that you can still click on symbol "." and it will write many dots in txtbox.Here is only one part of my code that you need

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
<style>
    button {
        user-select: none; 
        font-size:23px; 
        width:80px ; 
        height: 70px; 
        font-family:bold;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-color: gray;
    }
    .ope{
        background: rgb(96, 250, 199);
    }
    .num:focus {
        background: lime;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<input id="txtBox" type="text" style="text-align: right;font-size:60px;width: 325px;height: 125px; font-family: bold;" />
<br />
<button onclick="Click(event)" class="ope">C</button>
<button onclick="Click(event)" class="ope">delete</button>
<button onclick="Click(event)" class="ope">+/-</button>
<button onclick="Click(event)" class="ope">+</button>

<br />

<button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">1</button>
<button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">2</button>
<button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">3</button>
<button onclick="Click(event)" class="ope">-</button>

<br />

<button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">4</button>
<button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">5</button>
<button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">6</button>
<button onclick="Click(event)" class="ope">*</button>

<br />

<button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">7</button>
<button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">8</button>
<button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">9</button>
<button onclick="Click(event)" class="ope">/</button>

<br />

<button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">0</button>
<button onclick="Click(event)" id="ope">.</button>
<button onclick="Click(event)" id="equalto" style="background: rgb(206, 37, 206);user-select: none;font-size:25px; width:160px ; height: 70px; font-family:bold;">=</button>

<script>
    var nums = document.getElementById("num")
    var operator = document.getElementById("ope")
    var textbox = document.getElementById("txtBox")
    var counter = 0

    function Click(e) {
        var but = e.target;
        var maxamount = 9;
        var dot = 1
        if (but.innerText != "=" && but.innerText != "delete") {
            textbox.value += but.innerText
            if (but.innerText == "C") {
                textbox.value = "0"
            }
            else if (textbox.value[0] == "." || textbox.value[0] == "0" || textbox.value[0] == "+" || textbox.value[0] == "-" || textbox.value[0] == "/" || textbox.value[0] == "*") {
                textbox.value = ""
            }
            else if (textbox.value.length > maxamount) {
                textbox.value = textbox.value.substring(0, maxamount)
            }
            else if (textbox.value.includes == "+/-") {
                textbox.value*= -1
            }
            if (!textbox.value.includes('.') && textbox.value != "") {
                textbox.value+="."
            }
            else{

            }
        }

        else {
            textbox.value = eval(textbox.value)
        }
        if (but.innerText == "delete") {
            textbox.value = textbox.value.substring(0, textbox.value.length - 1);
        }
        if (textbox.value == "NaN" || textbox.value == "undefine") {
            textbox.value = ""
        }

    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's unclear how your sample above would continuously keep adding dots (.). It's possible it's how your getting the textbox and the value each time. We would need to see a bit more code - perhaps the HTML of the button + textbox as well as a bit more javascript code

Comment: @Prescott if you need full code , I just edited you can take a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Please try below Click function,

      <script>
        var nums = document.getElementById("num");
        var operator = document.getElementById("ope");
        var textbox = document.getElementById("txtBox");
        var counter = 0
        var dotReset=true;
        function Click(e) {
            var but = e.target;
            var maxamount = 9;
            var dot = 1;

            if (but.innerText != "=" && but.innerText != "delete") {
                if (but.innerText != ".") {
                    textbox.value += but.innerText;
                    if (but.innerText == "+" || but.innerText == "-" || but.innerText == "*" || but.innerText == "/"){
                        dotReset=true;
                    }
                }

                if (but.innerText == "C") {
                    textbox.value = "0";
                    dotReset=true;
                }
                else if (textbox.value[0] == "." || textbox.value[0] == "0" || textbox.value[0] == "+" || textbox.value[0] == "-" || textbox.value[0] == "/" || textbox.value[0] == "*") {
                    textbox.value = "";
                    dotReset=true;
                }
                else if (textbox.value.length > maxamount) {
                    textbox.value = textbox.value.substring(0, maxamount);
                }
                else if (textbox.value.includes == "+/-") {
                    textbox.value*= -1;
                }
                if (but.innerText == ".") {

                    if(dotReset){
                        if (textbox.value != "") {
                                textbox.value+="."
                                dotReset=false;
                            }
                    }

                    }
            }
            else {
                textbox.value = eval(textbox.value)
            }
            if (but.innerText == "delete") {
                textbox.value = textbox.value.substring(0, textbox.value.length - 1);
            }
            if (textbox.value == "NaN" || textbox.value == "undefine") {
                textbox.value = ""
            }

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for aswering,but both of the scenarios outputs nothing(( If you need full code,I just edited previous code.You can take a look at it.

Comment: It outputs numbers,but still you can add as many dots as you want.It still don't prevent it.But thank you for trying

Comment: Thank you very much, it really works.Just one question,is it possible to make it not only for "." but for all operations? Just asking.

Comment: It is possible, little more effort required.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is with the conditions (your code considers the *dot* button as the other buttons and, hence, outputs the *"."* every time). You should add a condition for the *dot* button. You may rewrite your code like the following:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById("txtBox")

function Click(e) {
  var but = e.target;
  if (but.innerText != "=" && but.innerText != "delete") {
     if (but.innerText == ".") {
        if (!textbox.value.includes('.') && textbox.value != "") {
           textbox.value += "."
        }
     }
     else{
        textbox.value += but.innerText
     }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sparing time to help me,but right now it starts to output double dots(( If you need I edited my code and showed all of it